# How to move multiple objects to a single point?

Tags: objects, transforms

I don't really know if I am asking the question correctly. If you notice the picture, the objects are being pulled towards a single point (as seen by all those green lines). It doesn't look like they are using <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, or <kbd>S</kbd>. I'm curious as to the method behind what this person is using.

[image]

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org will help you.

Comment: Its *really* hard to tell what is going on there, is that a tutorial? If so post a link to it.

Comment: "If you notice the picture" - I noticed the picture, but couldn't figure out what it was supposed to show...

Comment: you fixed the screenshot! (un-downvoted, and upvoted)

Answer (score 3):

This effect is what happens when you transform (move) several objects along one of their local axis. You can tell this because in the status bar in the screenshot it says 'along Local Y'.

Each object in that screenshot has been rotated so it's Y axis is pointing inwards or outwards:

[image]

Then the *Transformation orientation* in the 3D header has been set to *Local*, which means each object's local axis will be taken into account during the transformation:

[image]

With all the objects selected, pressing <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> or moving the 3D Manipulator will start a local transformation on each object's local axis (the green lines):

[image]

Comment: Ahh, good call & correction, I started along this path before the last updated screenshot, so I didn't quite catch that, as I was already down my own thought process.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a group with a parent.

The reason for the Green Color explains the group part.

The influence all coming from the same place indicates that there is most likely a common parent amongst the grouped items.

[image]

[image]

And if they are not using <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, OR <kbd>S</kbd>, then they are probably using manipulators like the following:

[image]

**OR**

It most likely has animation keyframes or drivers controlling this.

---

Per your update on your question:

Here is the Shape Key version of this same concept:

[image]

Comment: I have added a new snapshot. It is a timelapse video of the tree from the "Monkaa DVD."

Comment: OK, the screenshot shows shapekeys, that's animatable (keyframe-able), you want to study up on shape keys.